# Navigation graph- how to mange the navigation drawer using navigation graph with custom fragment in the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation-graph

I'm facing an issue that i have to use fragment in a navigation drawer (To manage custom designs). How can I manage the Navigation graph in this navigation drawer?

Comment: please add the code that you have tried with the expected and obtained result so that we can help....thank you....happy coding

Comment: You can put a FrameLayout inside NavigationView and inflate the Fragment on that view from the MainActivity